# wildcard bundle ID error Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, bundle-identifier

I have a wildcard bundle ID

> com.chatAt*

which I am setting for bundle identifier for my project in Xcode. However, I am getting an error

> (null): error: CFBundleIdentifier 'com.chatAt*' contains illegal
>   character '*'

After looking things up on the apple website it states that

> you need to replace the asterisk with an appropriate string using the
>   reverse-DNS format

and I am not sure what exactly is meant by 'reverse-DNS' format. Is anyone able to help with this? Thanks in advance

Comment: change  'com.chatAt*' to com.chatAt.yourAppName

Comment: Should the app name be from my itunes connect app name

Answer (score 0):

Reverse DNS format is just a domain name, backwards. For example, `com.stackoverflow`. In order to avoid name collisions, bundle IDs usually have the format reverse DNS name + name of application, where reverse DNS name is the reversed form of a domain name under your control. For example, a bundle ID for "MyApp" might be `com.example.MyApp`.

Comment: I changed it to com.chatAt.chatAt, but after validating I get the error 'no software with CFBundleIdentifier of com.chatAt.chatAt exists'. My app on iTunes Connect has app id with bundle id of com.chat*.

Comment: you should not use wildcard app ID for the appstore

Answer (score -1):

1. Make sure the device you want to run is added into provisioning profile com.chatAt*
2. Check the certifcate matches your provisioning profile.
3. Download the provisioning profile for com.chatAt* and the certificate.
4. Set the BundleID of your app to be com.chatAt.ChatAtSomething.
5. Set the same provisioning profile and certificate in xcode

Comment: All these answers presuppose prior knowledge of where to set these in xcode. For those who are new to xcode, this answer assumes too much.